# Gerar Runnable Jar a partir de um projeto Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar

Estou com dificuldade para estar gerando um arquivo Jar da minha aplicação a partir do Maven, segui o seguinte tutorial.

[Mkyoung.com](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/maven-create-a-fat-jar-file-one-jar-example/)

Ele chega a gerar o Jar mas com um tamanho super reduzido e na hora de executar pelo CMD ele apresenta a seguinte mensagem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu Build do Pom.xml está da seguinte forma:

```
<build>
    <finalName>SisAcademia</finalName>
    <plugins>

      <!-- download source code in Eclipse, best practice -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
            <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
            <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Set a compiler level -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Make this jar executable -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
           <archive>
             <manifest>
            <mainClass>br.com.tamarozzi.app.Main</mainClass>
             </manifest>
           </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
```

Sessão do arquivo Pom onde está as dependências:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- JUnit testing framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Outros -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>       

    <!-- Hibernate resources -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>20030825.184428</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>20030825.183949</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Tiles Apache -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Miglayout -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.miglayout</groupId>
        <artifactId>miglayout</artifactId>
        <version>${miglayout.version}</version>
    </dependency>   

    <!-- JDataChooser -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.toedter</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcalendar</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SwingX -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.swinglabs</groupId>
        <artifactId>swingx</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Como estão definidos os escopos, "Scope", das suas dependências? Adianto que provavelmente o problema está nelas, elas devem estar como "Provided", que neste caso seriam fornecidas por que executa o projeto. Poste o trecho das dependências.

Comment: Celso, eu sou novato em Spring ] Hibernate / Maven, apenas desenvolvi o projeto seguindo as diretrizes do Spring. Por favor se puder detalhar o problema que está ocorrendo ficarei muito grato. Adicionei na pergunta o que você me pediu.

Comment: Veja que a partir do item 4 do tutorial que você está seguindo, ocorre o mesmo erro, que você teve. Siga o item 5 do tutorial que deve resolver o seu problema. Quanto às dependências, parece estar tudo ok.

Comment: Segui o seu comentário baseando no tutorial do Mkyoung e o sistema não encontrou a main, como eu declaro a main? segue a imagem do erro:http://prntscr.com/8e12z9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme seu [próprio tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/maven-create-a-fat-jar-file-one-jar-example/), o Jar gerado pelo Maven não incluirá as dependências.

A solução proposta pelo tutorial é utilizar o plugin [One-Jar](http://onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/mavensite/usage.html) para gerar um *Uber Jar* incluindo as classes do seu projeto e todas as dependências:

```
<!-- Includes the runtime dependencies -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.dstovall</groupId>
    <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>one-jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<!-- One-Jar is in the googlecode repository -->
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com</id>
        <url>http://onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Executando o comando:

```
mvn package
```

Você obeterá um segundo jar com todas as dependências.

Para rodá-lo use:

```
java -jar SisAcademia.one-jar.jar
```

Alternativamente você pode também pode utilizar o [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/).

---

P.S.: Eu não sou muito fã de Uber Jars, prefiro copiar as dependências para uma pasta `lib` e ajustar o *class path* de acordo. Veja [essa resposta do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13620788/664577) para uma receita de bolo utilizando o [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/index.html) e o [Maven JAR Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/).

Comment: Segui o seu comentário baseando no tutorial do Mkyoung e o sistema não encontrou a main, como eu declaro a main? segue a imagem do erro: http://prntscr.com/8e12z9

Comment: Anthony, eu sou uma mula quadrada pra esse tipo de coisa, poderia me dizer qual é a melhora maneira de gerar o Jar já com as dependência?

Comment: Assumindo que o caminho está correto, sua configuração para o `maven-jar-plugin` seria o suficiente (`<mainClass>br.com.tamarozzi.app.Main</mainClass>`). Isso cria uma entrada em `META-INF\MANIFEST.MF` com o conteudo `Main-Class: br.com.tamarozzi.app.Main` (vocé pode abrir o JAR com uma ferramenta qualquer de zip para verificar).

Comment: Veja também que você está com conflitos entre suas dependências. Em uma primeira analise eu chutaria que são dependências transitivas do Spring e hibernate (e.g., uma das bibliotecas está dependendo do *javassist 3.7* e outra do *javassist 3.18.1-GA*). Para resolver esse problema eu  usaria o [BOM do Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-maven-bom) e evitaria especificar versões manualmente.

Comment: eu fui atras do tal 'onejar' dei uma olhada que ele tem algumas tag para declarar a class main, o jar agora está encontrando o main o problema é que ele não encontra a pasta resources, eu usei algumas imagens e até mesmo arquivo properties estão dentro desta pasta 'src/main/resources' e o sistema não consegue encontrar, segue a imagem da minha arvore de diretórios http://prntscr.com/8e4nhk . Como apontar as path das pasta resources?

Comment: Acho que vale a pena abrir uma pergunta diferente com a estrutura, código que está tentando abrir os recursos e o Stack trace. Por padrão tudo o que está em resources deve ser copiado para dentro do jar (novamente, você pode checar com uma ferramenta qualquer de zip)